# Some of the collisions are not responding

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

im developing a game; its like a space craft going horizontally and enemy crafts coming oppositely..Enemies are destroyed only when it collides with the trail of the craft.

Here is the main class:

```
public function Velocity() {
        //int static var
        trailspeed = 10;
        shipspeed = 5;
        //init ship//
        ship = new Ship();
        ship.x = 337;
        ship.y = 216;
        //int arrays
        enemies = new Array();
        //init starting state
        score = 0;
        health = 100;
        //Events
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, motion);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyup);
        //init container and trail
        _cont = new MovieClip();
        //addChild
        addChild(_cont);
        addChild(ship);
        timerset();
    }
    public function motion(e:Event){
        //adding the trails
        trail = new Trail();
        trail.x = ship.x;
        trail.y = ship.y;
        _cont.addChild(trail);
        checkcollision();
    }
    public function checkcollision(){
        for(var _e:int = enemies.length - 1; _e >=0; _e--){
            for(var _t:int = _cont.numChildren - 1; _t >=0; _t--){
                if(enemies[_e].hitTestObject(_cont.getChildAt(_t))){
                enemies[_e].remove();
                return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function removeenemies(_e:Enemy){
        for(var i in enemies){
            if(enemies[i] == _e){
                enemies.splice(_e);
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the Enemy class:

```
public class Enemy extends MovieClip {
    private var _speed:Number;

    public function Enemy(ypos, speed) {
        this.x = 550;
        this.y = ypos;
        _speed = speed;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, motion);

    }
    public function motion(e:Event){
        this.x -= _speed;
        checkoffscreen();
    }
    public function remove(){
        MovieClip(parent).removeenemies(this);
        MovieClip(parent).removeChild(this);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, motion);
        return;
    }
    public function checkoffscreen(){
        if(this.x < 0){
            MovieClip(parent).removeenemies(this);
            MovieClip(parent).removeChild(this);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, motion);
        }
    }
}

}
```

The problem here is after 2 or 3 successful collision detections one goes undetected.. and hence the chances is like 2/3 ...how can i program a 100% successful collision???pls help

Comment: I think that your problem come from this line : `for(var _e:int = enemies.length - 1; _e >=0; _e--)`, because I don't know when and where  you added your `Enemy` objects, but I think that after some time `enemies` array is empty and here don't forget `Enemy.checkoffscreen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the answer.
the problem was with the removeenemies function

replacing splice(_e) wtih splice(_e, 1) solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend not to delete objects from within themselves, instead have a simple `isDead` boolean inside the the `Enemy` and in the main class when you loop through enemies check if `isDead` is set to true, if so then remove the object from the array and delete it from the Stage; no need for `removeenemies()`.

Back to the real problem you're having. You're doing a good job iterating through the list of enemies in **reverse** since you do expect to remove some objects, that of course results in shift of entries in the array.

It's hard to say what's wrong with this code. I'd say lose `removeenemies()`. Move any collision testing inside the `Enemy` and in the `Main` keep everything in a nice linear `update` function like so:

```
public function update() {
    for(var i:int = enemies.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
        var enemy:Enemy = enemies[i];

        enemy.checkCollision(); // Can set isDead = true;

        if(enemy.isDead) {
            enemies.splice(i);
            removeChild(enemy);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working..same error successful collision is only 2/3

Comment: Hm, any reason why you're colliding with everything that's on the stage? Would be smarter to store collidables in another array and check enemies against it for collisions. Also do you take any measures to make sure objects aren't checking for collision on it themselves? Because as we know that test always passes.

Comment: No i don't think that's the problem. Its like collision function is not 100% efficient